Piechart not update the values already exist in javafx
I want when I press the add button to add a specific value to the piechart, that this value be update if it previously existed in the piechart. For example, here he added the Java language twice. I want him to combine the old java value with the passed value and not add another Java. Here is my code:
package charts;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class PieChartController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private TextField name, value;
    @FXML
    private PieChart pieChart;
    
    private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        pieChart.setData(data);
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void btnAdd() {
        
        
        data.add(new PieChart.Data(name.getText(), Integer.valueOf(value.getText())));
        pieChart.setData(data);
    }
}


Can any one help please?

Update the data; the listening chart will update itself in response, for example.

The value of a PieChart.Data is observable; updating it will cause the chart to update. You need to search the chart's data list for one with the given name. If one exists, then update its value. Otherwise, create a new data and add it to the chart.
For example:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var chart = new PieChart();

    var nameField = new TextField();
    nameField.setPromptText("Name");

    var valueField = new TextField();
    valueField.setPromptText("Value");

    var addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setDefaultButton(true);
    addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
      e.consume();

      var name = nameField.getText().strip();
      var value = valueField.getText().strip();
      if (!name.isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
        double parsedValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
        chart.getData().stream()
            .filter(data -> data.getName().equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresentOrElse(
                existingData -> existingData.setPieValue(parsedValue),
                () -> chart.getData().add(new PieChart.Data(name, parsedValue)));
      }
    });

    var top = new HBox(10, nameField, valueField, addButton);
    top.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    top.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    var root = new BorderPane();
    root.setTop(top);
    root.setCenter(chart);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(Main.class);
  }
}

Note the above implementation uses a Stream and an Optional to update the chart's data or add new data. The following is what it could look like without streams:
addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
  e.consume();

  var name = nameField.getText().strip();
  var value = valueField.getText().strip();
  if (!name.isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
    double parsedValue = Double.parseDouble(value);

    boolean updated = false;
    for (var data : chart.getData()) {
      if (data.getName().equals(name)) {
        data.setPieValue(parsedValue);
        updated = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!updated) {
      chart.getData().add(new PieChart.Data(name, parsedValue));
    }
  }
});

Another approach is to keep a Map<String, PieChart.Data>:
var nameToDataMap = new HashMap<String, PieChart.Data>();
chart.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<PieChart.Data>) c -> {
  while (c.next()) {
    c.getRemoved().forEach(d -> nameToDataMap.remove(d.getName()));
    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(d -> nameToDataMap.put(d.getName(), d));
  }
});

Then use it like so:
addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
  e.consume();

  var name = nameField.getText().strip();
  var value = valueField.getText().strip();
  if (!name.isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
    double parsedValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
    var data = nameToDataMap.get(name);
    if (data == null) {
      chart.getData().add(new PieChart.Data(name, parsedValue));
    } else {
      data.setPieValue(parsedValue);
    }
  }
});

But note with this approach, or at least how it's implemented here, you must not update the name of any PieChart.Data while it's present in the PieChart. Also, given the almost-guaranteed small size of the data list, using a map could be more effort than it's worth since linearly searching the list will take pretty much no time.

For me, the stream method is very clean and easy to read and understand, with little risk of error when written.  I am very glad that such functions were added to Java.

I'm trying to picture a pie chart with so many values that streaming through the data caused performance issues.

@jewelsea I agree. In many cases, streams make things much cleaner and less error prone (and I think this case qualifies).

@DaveB Would certainly be unreadable.
